# Is eval/alarm is executing?

Tags: perl

I'm writing a quick script to test the failures and interpreted traffic of a load balancer. I want it to keep trying to make connections after it can't connect to one host or another. My current script doesn't look like it's executing the eval block in the mkcnct sub, and I can't figure out why. Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use Net::HTTP;
use Getopt::Std;

my %opts;

getopts('ht:',\%opts);

my @hostlist ("www.foo.com","www1.foo.com","www2.foo.com");

my $timeout;

if ($opts{t} =~ /\d+/) {
 $timeout = $opts{t} + time();
} else {
 $timeout = 3600 + time();
}

while ($timeout < time()) {
 foreach my $host (@hostlist) {
  my $cnct = mkcnct($host);
  if ($cnct) { mkreq($cnct) };
 }
}

sub mkreq {
 my $cnct = shift;
 my $time = gettime();
 my $out;
 $cnct->write_request(GET => "/index.html");
 ($out->{code},$out->{message},%{$out->{headers}}) = $cnct->read_response_headers;
 printf "%s\t%s - Size %d\tLast modified %s\n", $time, $out->{message}, $out->{headers}{'Content-Length'}, $out->{headers}{'Last-Modified'};
 $out = "";
 $cnct->write_request(GET => "/pki/ca.crl");
 ($out->{code},$out->{message},%{$out->{headers}}) = $cnct->read_response_headers;
 printf "%s\t%s - Size %d\tLast modified %s\n", $time, $out->{message}, $out->{headers}{'Content-Length'}, $out->{headers}{'Last-Modified'};
}

sub mkcnct {
 my $host = shift;
 my $time = gettime();
 my $cnct;
 eval{
  local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { print "$time\tCannot connect to $host\n"};
  alarm(2);
  $cnct = Net::HTTP->new(Host => $host);
  alarm(0);
 };
 alarm(0);
 return($cnct);
}

sub gettime {
 my @time = localtime(time);
 my $out;
 $out = sprintf "%d\/%d\/%d %d:%d", ($time[4] + 1), $time[3], ($time[5] % 100 ), $time[2], $time[1];
 return($out);
}
```

Comment: You should always check the return value of `eval` by doing `if($@) { print $@; }` directly afterwards.

Comment: Using [LWPx::ParanoidAgent](http://p3rl.org/LWPx::ParanoidAgent) and setting the `timeout` attribute is perhaps a more robust approach.

Answer (score -3):

Try replacing return($cnct); with return $cnct; in mkcnct. You might want to revue the docs on returning scalars and lists

Comment: -1 both are the same. Compare output of `perl -MO=Deparse -e'return($cnct)'` and `perl -MO=Deparse -e'return $cnct'`.

Comment: 1) Subs can only return lists of scalars. There is no difference between returning a scalar and returning a list of one scalar. 2) Parens almost never create lists, and here is no exception. Just like in `(5+5)*4` and in `my @a = (1,2,3);`, at most they affect precedence.

Comment: @daxim, You really should be using `-MO=Concise` to check for differences. Deparse is not 100% accurate.